# How to display date in reverse order using PHP?

Tags: php

Just need a little help here. How can I display the date output of PHP in reverse order?
For example if I have a date like this.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d"); //example output 2013-01-01

My expected output should be: 130-210-10 //01-01-2013

How can i do that?
```

Comment: The formats of your input and desired outputs are unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change the order of parameters in `date()`:

```
echo strrev(date('d-m-Y'));
```

If you can't change the order of the parameters in `date()`:

```
echo implode('-', array_map('strrev', explode('-', $date)));
```

Comment: Ok it works but what if I include a format like this 
xxx-xxx-xxx example 310-201-01?

Comment: @RochelleCanale the first will reverse the entire string: `10-102-013`,  the second will reverse each chunk, delimited by the hyphen: `013-102-10`

Comment: how can i format my date output into ##-###-###? And how can i include delimeter?

Answer (score 3):

Using `strrev`

```
$date = strrev(date("d-m-Y"));
```

Note how I also changed positions of the parameters in `date` according to your expected output.

See also:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Answer (score 2):

Discover [strrev()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php):

```
$date = strrev(date("d-m-Y"));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `strrev()`

```
$date = strrev(date("Y-m-d"));
```